# Angular.js promises $http.get

Tags: angularjs, promise

i have service which makes an $HTTP.GET request, at first i tried to access the object $$state but the value inside was undefined, so i went and red about promises and asynchronous calls here:
 http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

after i red everything i tried again as guided but still it doesn't work for me :-(, please advise, i want to access the values object.

```
service:
function ConnectMe($http) {

function OnAction() {

    this.create = function (search, key) {
        return $http.get("https://www.tastekid.com/api/similar?q=" + search + "&verbose=1&k=" + key).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });

    };
}

var connection = new OnAction();

return function () {
    return connection;
};
}


controller:
function TasteConroller($scope, ConnectMe) {
$scope.apiKey = "https://www.tastekid.com/api/similar?q=" + $scope.UserPick + "&verbose=1&k=254357-MatureAm-A31YEAIX";
$scope.UserPick = "red+hot+chili+peppers";
$scope.Key = "254357-MatureAm-A31YEAIX";
var srv = ConnectMe();

srv.create($scope.UserPick, $scope.Key).then(function(data) {
    $scope.results = data;
}), function() {
    $scope.error = 'unable to get the ponies';
};

console.log($scope.results);
```

Comment: *it doesn't work for me* is much too vague. Post all the relevant code, create a plunkr reproducing the issue, tell precisely what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Thanks for reading this article (I wrote it) :-) Note that console.log($scope.results); will always print undefined, since it's executed **before** the callback function passed to then(). That's the same trap as I describe in the section **So let’s fix the code again**. You fell into it :-( Asynchronous code is asynchronous.

Comment: hu... i used console.log as my indicator, when u said it won't work i tried to print it on the screen, and it worked :-)...i guess i have a lot of work to figure out hot to arrange all that mess without console.log

Comment: You need to understand the principle of asynchronism. You can't just put a toast in the toaster (i.e. call srv.create()), and start eating it right after (i.e. calling console.log()). You need to do something else while and the toaster does its job. You can only eat the toast (i.e. call console.log()) when the toaster tells you that the toast is ready (i.e. when the promise calls the callback `function(data)` passed to then()). So, put the console.log() **inside** that function.

Comment: huu right, i understand now! thanks man, not just for that but for all the effort u put in ur articles it's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service code looks a little suspect.  I normally create a service like this;

```
function ServiceFunc( $http, $q ){
    return {
        OnAction: function( search, key ){ 
            return $http.get(...)
                   .then( function( rsp ){ return rsp.data.foo })
                   .catch( function( err ){ $q.reject( err )})
    }
}
```

I think you may have had a deeper level of functions whereby you weren't actually calling it.